# cakephp 3 lock file property

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application that create many php process to read file.
Sometimes process read the same file so I need to lock file when a process read It.

The application need to read only one times a file and after delete It. 
Sometimes two process read the same file and this is a big problem.

I have create many process that every one loop through a folder, read all file, and delete it. 
I don't want that two process read the same file, but the problem is that the process works simultaneously.

code of every process :

```
public function readAllXmlAndSave()
    $xml_files = glob(TMP . 'xml/*.xml');
    foreach($xml_files as $fileXml){
        $explStr = explode('/', $fileXml);
        $filename = $explStr[count($explStr) - 1];
        $path = TMP . '/xml/' . $filename;
        $file = new File($path, false);

        if($file->exists()){
           $string = $file->read();
           //some work
           $file->close();
           $file->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

I have create a simple script to understand how lock file works into cakephp 3 but seems that property `lock` doesn't work as I aspected.

code

```
$path = TMP . '/xml/test.xml'; //inside there is "HELLO"
$file = new File($path, false);

$string = $file->read();
echo($string);
$file->lock = true;

$string2 = $file->read();
echo($string2);

$string3 = $file->read();
echo($string3);
```

I aspected that only  the first `echo` work not the other.. Why I get always:

```
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
```

and not only  the first echo?

```
HELLO
```

Comment: `File::read()` releases the lock after reading the data, so that's the expected behavior. Maybe you want to describe the actual problem that you are trying to solve by locking a file.

Comment: I have multiple process that read sometimes the same file, so I would like that when a process read a file It lock it so any other process can read that file. is possible? @ndm

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri edit the question please, don't clarify questions with comments.

Comment: CakePHP uses `LOCK_SH`, ie shared locks, which can be aquired by multiple processes for the same file at any given time. You'd have to manually lock using `LOCK_EX` I guess. But don't forget that PHP may use advisory locking, ie locking will only be respected by other `flock()` calls.

Comment: Also note that youe example code is not suited for testing the bahvior of overlapping processes, what you are doing there are sequential reads.

Comment: I have a cycle to read in a folder, into my question I thought that could working to understand the logic of file. I have tried to change manually LOCK_SH to LOCK_EX but the result is the same :( @ndm

Comment: Yes, they are the same because `File::read()` still releases the lock after it finished reading from the file. So maybe what you actually want to achieve is preventing writes to any of the files in a directory while you are reading them? You may want to make that clear in your question.

Comment: I need only to read file one times but sometimes processes read the same file and I don't know how to lock with cakephp 3. I update the question @ndm

Comment: Well, looking at your updated question, If you'd wanted to handle this with locks on the XML files, then you'd have to acquire exclusive locks for all files first, and if that is successful, read and delete them. I don't think that's an overly good idea, not only because you may run into the open file handle limit rather easily.

Comment: I'd probably instead try to ensure that the whole method is not being run, something quick & dirty could be to use a dummy file which when locked would prevent the whole methods logic to run. But in the end it depends on the context, like the when/why/how of the files being generated and the method being invoked.